# Enumerating different distribution of balls in boxes with capacity constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

i have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7662561/4023805). My question is that there are m boxes and n balls. Boxes are distinguishable but not the balls. Each box has a maximum capacity. I want to enumerate each possible distribution. For example: if 3 boxes and 5 balls with each box's max being 3, one distribution is $[2,2,1]$. It is easy to find how many such distributions are possible by using the theory of generating functions. I am not interested in that.

I am not able to think an algo which will help enumerate all such solutions like:-

$[2,2,1]$

$[1,2,2]$

$[3,1,1]$

$[4,0,1]$

$[4,1,0]$

... and so on

An algorithmic recipe is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Visual Basic program in Excel a while back which does this. It has the added feature that I can individually set the capacity of each box.

Here's the program (prettyfied a little so variables match your notation):

```
Const MaxBox = 10 'Maximum boxes. M must be less than this.
Dim MaxCapacityBox(MaxBox) As Integer
Dim SumMax(MaxBox) As Integer
Dim M As Integer 'Number of boxes
Dim BallsInBox(MaxBox) As Integer 'Current number of balls in box
Dim R As Integer
Dim N As Integer 'Number of balls
Dim SumTo(MaxBox) As Integer 'Total balls already placed in a box

Sub Macro1()
  N = 5
  M = 3
  Init
  Distribute
End Sub

Sub Init()
  'Allocate max capacities to each box. Only box numbers < M are relevant.
  MaxCapacityBox(1) = 3
  MaxCapacityBox(2) = 3
  MaxCapacityBox(3) = 3
  MaxCapacityBox(4) = 0
  MaxCapacityBox(5) = 0
  MaxCapacityBox(6) = 0
  SumMax(M) = MaxCapacityBox(M)
  'Find the total capacity of boxes from box i to the last box (box M)
  For i = M - 1 To 1 Step -1
    SumMax(i) = MaxCapacityBox(i) + SumMax(i + 1)
  Next i
End Sub

Sub Distribute()
Dim K As Integer
  'Do initial filling and print result
  K = 0
  SumTo(K) = 0
  Extra = N - SumTo(K)
  R = 2
  If Extra <= SumMax(K + 1) Then
    'Fill Extra
    Do While Extra > 0
      K = K + 1
      If Extra > MaxCapacityBox(K) Then
        BallsInBox(K) = MaxCapacityBox(K)
      Else
        BallsInBox(K) = Extra
      End If
      SumTo(K) = SumTo(K - 1) + BallsInBox(K)
      Extra = Extra - BallsInBox(K)
    Loop
    'Print result
    R = R + 1
    For i = 1 To K
      Cells(R, i + 2).Value = BallsInBox(i)
    Next i
    If K = M Then
      K = K - 1
    End If
  End If
  'Do main loop
  Do While K >= 1
    If BallsInBox(K) > 0 Then
      BallsInBox(K) = BallsInBox(K) - 1
      SumTo(K) = SumTo(K) - 1
      Extra = N - SumTo(K)
      If Extra <= SumMax(K + 1) Then
        'Fill Extra
        Do While Extra > 0
          K = K + 1
          If Extra > MaxCapacityBox(K) Then
            BallsInBox(K) = MaxCapacityBox(K)
          Else
            BallsInBox(K) = Extra
          End If
          SumTo(K) = SumTo(K - 1) + BallsInBox(K)
          Extra = Extra - BallsInBox(K)
        Loop
        'Print result
        R = R + 1
        For i = 1 To K
          Cells(R, i + 2).Value = BallsInBox(i)
        Next i
        If K = M Then
          K = K - 1
        End If
      Else
        K = K - 1
      End If
    Else
      K = K - 1
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

The basic algorithm is the following:

1. Starting with the first box, fill each box with as many balls as possible. This is the first permutation.
2. At the last box in which balls were inserted, see if $1$ ball can be moved to the next box. If so, remove that ball from that box and move it to the next box. That's the next permutation and you go to 2. If no ball can be moved, go to 3.
3. Go back to the box from which $1$ ball was moved and see if an additional ball can be moved. If so, move the sum of balls (in the beginning this is $2$ balls) downstream and go to 2. If no further balls are available, go one box upstream and try again. When you are at box $1$ and no further balls can be moved downstream, you are done.

Here's the result of running the program with $M=3$, $N=5$ and max capacity of all boxes at $3$:

[image]